# Matching 2 columns in a row, then copy using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that is copying from another workbook based on a specific name in a selected column. For example, when the macro is run, it will copy an entire row when "John" is in column C of the row. Below is my working code.

```
Sub UpdateGreen_Click()
Dim copyStartCell As Long
Dim readLastCell As Long
Dim manager As String
Dim A
Dim B
Dim C
Dim d
Dim sheet As String


copyStartCell = 4

readLastCell = masterWorkBook.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

For x = 4 To readLastCell
cell = "C" & x
manager = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value

' CHANGES MADE TO NAME HERE:
    If UCase(manager) = "ALIA" Then

        cell = "A" & x
        A = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
        cell = "B" & x
        B = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
        cell = "C" & x
        C = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
        cell = "D" & x
        d = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value

        'copy

        cell = "A" & copyStartCell
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value = A
        cell = "B" & copyStartCell
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value = B
         cell = "C" & copyStartCell
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value = C
         cell = "D" & copyStartCell
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value = d

          copyStartCell = copyStartCell + 1

   End If

 Next x

    End Sub
```

Instead of looking at one column (the name column C; John), is it possible to look at two columns (Column A; Number and Column C; John) and then only proceed to copying the data?

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly and another conditional to your current one?

```
    Sub UpdateGreen_Click()
Dim copyStartCell As Long
Dim readLastCell As Long
Dim manager As String
Dim A
Dim B
Dim C
Dim d
Dim sheet As String

copyStartCell = 4

readLastCell = masterWorkBook.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

For x = 4 To readLastCell
cell = "C" & x
cellA= "A" & x
manager = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value

' CHANGES MADE TO NAME HERE:
    If UCase(manager) = "ALIA" and masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cellA).Value = "Number value" Then

    cell = "A" & x
    A = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
    cell = "B" & x
    B = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
    cell = "C" & x
    C = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value
    cell = "D" & x
    d = masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cell).Value

    'copy

    cell = "A" & copyStartCell
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value = A
    cell = "B" & copyStartCell
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value = B
     cell = "C" & copyStartCell
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value = C
     cell = "D" & copyStartCell
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range(cell).Value = d

          copyStartCell = copyStartCell + 1

   End If

 Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: I added the second conditional [and masterworkbook.worksheets("Master").range(cellA)], cellA is the column reference

Comment: "masterWorkBook.Worksheets("Master").Range(cellA).Value = "Number value" Then", does this means that in the Number Value column I need to input a specific number? Cause it's going to be a running number.

Comment: Yes, it is a single value that will be searched in column A. If it matches, it will be selected to copy